# IIF statement in SQL/ Informatica ( expression transformation) with two values

Tags: sql, informatica, iif

I have the following SQL statement which check for the presence of 000. But what if I want to check the presence of either 000 or 666? I tried using | but no luck.....

```
IIF(Field='000','TRUE','FALSE')
```

Comment: do you have to use `iif`?

Comment: whats other options? INSTR?

Comment: was thinking more along the lines of a `case` statement but an answer has been provided.

Comment: thanks for your help Ric!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What dbms are you using?

Anyways, I'll suggest CASE instead of iif and IN instead of || like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Field in('000','666') then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as Col1
FROM YourTable
```

EDIT:

For informatica, there are 1 of two options, Either use OR like this:

```
IIF(Field='000' or Field='666','TRUE','FALSE')
```

Or use IN like this:

```
IIF(Field in('000','666'),'TRUE','FALSE')
```

Comment: its actually in informatica - expression transformation which uses SQL syntax

Comment: @Nidhin_toms Then you should have mentioned it.. updated my answer look now

Answer (score 4):

Use `in`.

```
IIF(Field in ('000','666'),'TRUE','FALSE')
```